# ¿Cómo reccorrer el error de la pagina de envio whatsapp con puppeteer?

Tags: nodejs, whatsapp, puppeteer

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme.
Estoy intentando enviar mensaje whatsapp desde puppeter.

***1 - Mi codigo:***

```html
(async ()=>{

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto("https://web.whatsapp.com/", { waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
    await delay(40000);

    const nreg = await rest.executeQuery("select count(*) from customer");
    const result = await rest.executeQuery("select * from customer");
    const qtde = nreg.data[0][0][""];
  
    var i = 0;
    while (i < qtde) {
      //  console.log(i);
      var phone = result.data[0][i].phone;
      var message = result.data[0][i].message;
      
      await page.goto('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+'+phone+'&text='+message+'');
      await delay(10000);
      console.log("Enviando mensagem" + ' ' + phone);
      await page.click("span[data-testid='send']");
      await delay(10000);
      i++;
    }

})();
```

***2 - Mi ahorra un error cuando el numero és inválido*** 
Necessito obternelo para hacer los tratamientos y seguir adelante con los numeros restantes.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ZBx.png

***3 - El programa se aborta*** 
Error: No element found for selector: span[data-testid='send']
at assert (C:\projeto_wapp\wapp_tiwtch_puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\assert.js:26:15)
at DOMWorld.click (C:\projeto_wapp\wapp_tiwtch_puppeteer\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:347:32)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async C:\projeto_wapp\wapp_tiwtch_puppeteer\app_pupp_bd.js:34:7

Answer (score 0):

He logrado exito en mi pregunta.
He añadido un try catch para tratar las excepciones.

```
      try 
      {
          console.log("Mensagem enviada para:" + ' ' + phone );
          await page.click("span[data-testid='send']");
          await rest.executeQuery("update customer set enviado = 1 where id = " + idfone);

      }
      catch(e)
      {
          console.log("Erro ao enviar mensagem para:" + ' ' + phone );
          await rest.executeQuery("update customer set enviado = 0 where id = " + idfone );          
          i++;
          continue;
      }
      await delay(10000);
      i++;
    }
```